# image or video attachment field in MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, xamarin

I have a UI I am building in MonoTouch.Dialog. I want a UI field where a user can click and attach a photo or video from the gallery on their iPad to the form. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of iOS are you working with?

Comment: Perhaps something using this API could be of use: 
http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Introduction_to_CollectionViews

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple ImageElement as the UI field and an [UIImagePickerController](http://docs.xamarin.com/index.php?title=ios/recipes/Media/Video_and_Photos/Choose_a_Photo_From_the_Gallery&action=source) to allow user to select an image or video.